# Both cmath and numpy give "incorrect" value of asin(10)

Tags: python, numpy, math

I recently needed to quickly find the arcsine of 10.  I decided to use python to calculate it for me:

```
cmath.asin(10)
```

Based on experience I had expected a result in the 4th quadrant (positive real(pi/2) and negative imaginary).  Surprise... it returned the 1st quadrant result.  I tried numpy.arcsin as well... same result.  While it is true that the sine of the returned value is 10, I don't believe this is the **standard principal value** for the arcsine function.

```
>>> import math
>>> import numpy as np
>>> z=cmath.asin(10)
>>> z
(1.5707963267948966+2.993222846126381j)
>>> cmath.sin(z)
(9.999999999999998+6.092540900222251e-16j)
>>> z2=np.arcsin(10+0j)
>>> np.sin(z2)
(10+6.092540900222253e-16j)
```

I found this same result using numpy (as seen above).

**Is there a python module from which I can expect to get the standard principal values (i.e. follows the principal branch cuts) for complex valued functions?**  Or, is the notion of standard principal value too fluid at this point to expect consistency?

---

- Pushing through the discussion on the Wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions) section on complex values leads to the 4th quadrant solution.
- This is also true for an article (http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.413.5729&rep=rep1&type=pdf) published by a PSU mathematician on complex inverse trig functions.
- Wolfram Alpha gives the 4th quadrant solution. [image: wolfram alpha asin(10)]

Comment: `np.arcsin` explains how it handles complex inputs.  Since I'm a bit rusty about complex math, can you translate its `branch cuts` to/from your quandrants?

Comment: `sympy` gives `1.5707963267949 - 2.99322284612638⋅ⅈ`.  I think the `cmath` and `numpy` functions depend on the underlying `c` code, rather than implementing things afresh.

Comment: Fair enough. The key choice is about how to treat signed zeros and branch cuts: do you ignore the sign of the zero for the purposes of deciding which side of the branch cut you're on, or do you distinguish based on the sign of the zero? Distinguishing based on the zero sign gives some nice properties, like `asin(conj(z))` being consistently the same as `conj(asin(z))`, including all corner cases. But mathematically, it feels like a bit of a cheat.  BTW, I note that the docs of both Python and NumPy are misleading here, using wording like "continuous from below".

Comment: @hpaulj: No, `cmath` is not relying on the underlying C code. It does indeed implement things afresh, but it was a deliberate, conscious choice to follow Kahan's recommendations and the C standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `cmath` behaviour is *somewhat* standard, in that it's not limited to just `cmath` and NumPy: it also matches the behaviour recommended in Annex G of the C standards (at least, C99 and later), as well as the definitions laid out by William Kahan in his [paper](https://people.freebsd.org/%7Edas/kahan86branch.pdf) "Branch Cuts for Complex Elementary Functions", subtitled "Much Ado About Nothing's Sign Bit".

But what we're really seeing here is yet another divergence between the world of pure mathematics and the world of floating-point arithmetic.

The "standard" behaviour above is specific to mathematics performed using floating-point arithmetic, and in particular using floating-point arithmetic formats where there's a "negative zero" value that's distinct (equal, but distinct) from "positive zero". This includes the by now almost ubiquitous IEEE 754 floating-point standard.

The branch cuts in `cmath` match the "standard" mathematics ones (e.g., for `asin`, we make the cuts along the positive real axis from `1` to infinity, and along the negative real axis from `-1` to negative infinity), and as usual, the values on the subinterval `[-1, 1]` of the real line match the usual real `asin` function in both standard mathematics and the `cmath` module. Given that, continuity away from the branch cuts forces `cmath.asin` to agree with the standard mathematical definition everywhere except possibly *on* the branch cuts.

Mathematically, to extend `asin` to the branch cuts you need to choose whether to be "continuous from above" or "continuous from below" on each cut, and the usual choice for `asin` is to be continuous from below on `[1, inf)` and continuous from above on `(-inf, -1]`, which would give you the fourth-quadrant result for `asin(10)` that you expect. But if you're working with IEEE 754 floating-point, another option emerges: on the branch cut for `asin`, the imaginary part of the argument is always zero. You can now use the *sign* of the zero to determine which side of the branch cut you interpret the argument as lying on. So we get for example:

```
>>> from cmath import asin
>>> asin(complex(10.0, 0.0))  # 'top' of the branch cut
(1.5707963267948966+2.993222846126381j)
>>> asin(complex(10.0, -0.0))  # 'bottom' of the branch cut
(1.5707963267948966-2.993222846126381j)
```

This is similar to the way that the real-valued `atan2` function works in most languages: usually, `atan2(0.0, -1.0)` is defined to be `pi`, while `atan2(-0.0, -1.0)` is defined to be `-pi`; the sign of the zero is used to distinguish. Mathematically, it's a bit of a cheat, but it has some nice properties in floating-point land. For example, we get that `asin(z.conjugate())` is interchangeable with `asin(z).conjugate()` for all `z`, including all the floating-point special cases. And behaviour on quadrants is well-defined (if again you determine membership of each quadrant using the signs of the zeros where relevant).

As to your question about a Python module that gives the "standard" values, I'm not aware of one, though [@hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj) mentions SymPy in the comments. Or you could fudge the zero signs to force values to be interpreted the right way.